# How to change Scala version for sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I change Scala version in a sbt project?

I would like SBT to check whether the system's Scala version is correct and if it is not the case then download it.

Comment: In the new sbt 1.x, in the shell: `set scalaVersion := "2.13.1"`, or in build.sbt: `scalaVersion := "2.13.1"`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### xsbt (0.10+, including the latest 0.13.7)

Change `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt` to whatever Scala version your project should be using - see [.sbt build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html).

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
```

---

#### sbt:

As mentioned in [RunningSBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt), you can:

> You can temporarily switch to another version of Scala using `++<version>`.
>   This version does not have to be listed in your `build.scala.versions` property, but it does have to be in a repository or be a [local Scala](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LocalScala) version you have defined.

But the [CrossBuild page](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/CrossBuild) is more suited for what you want, as it shows in action how to change the `build.scala.versions` property.

So you should be able to

```
set build.scala.versions 2.7.7
reload
set build.scala.versions 2.8.0.RC2
reload
```

and each time trigger a compilation with a different Scala version.

Comment: @sheki: good point. I have added the xsbt configuration for changing the Scala version used for building your Scala project.

Comment: @sheki: see my build.sbt as a more complete example of what you usually change in a Scala project with xsbt: https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: A piece of information I found useful: In case you have a multi-project you can use `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.1"` in the main .sbt file to propagate the setting in all sub-projects.

Comment: @CristianVrabie when `scalaVersion` is defined in the root project's `build.sbt` that aggregates the other submodules, it will work fine, too. You don't need `in ThisBuild`.