# Using scala 2.9.2 with Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play project.  Unfortunately I am deserializing some case classes that were serialized using scala 2.9.2.  Since play uses 2.9.1 there is a InvalidClassException.

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.Option; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2832403187243187948, local class serialVersionUID = 7113474029577970182
```

Is it possible to force play to use scala 2.9.2?  The play project configuration seems to be doing a lot magically.  There's not much in `projects/Build.scala`.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    val appName         = "myproj"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Since 2.9.2 is binary compatible with 2.9.1 I should be able to force it to be used--but I have no idea how to!

Update: adding scala 2.9.2 as a dependency gives me the following error.

```
[error] {file:/home/schmmd/repo/openie-demo/}openiedemo/*:update: Version specified for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-lang;2.9.2 differs from Scala version in project (2.9.1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sbt plugin for Play 2.0.4 compatible with Scala 2.9.2 as play 2.0.4 was built on SBT 0.11.x. Play! upgraded to Scala 2.9.2 using SBT 0.12.x and this broke the backward compatibility of Play 2.0.4 to use Scala 2.9.2

However, there is a back-port for Scala 2.9.3. Change your scalaVersion to 2.9.3 in your Build file to use play 2.0.4 SBT plugin.

Answer (score 7):

try to update your Build.scala

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appDependencies = Seq(
       // Add your project dependencies here,
       "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.2",
      ...
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).setting(
      // Add your own project settings here
      scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I am trying right now, but I get `unresolved dependencies play#play_2.9.2;2.0.2: not found`

Comment: No it doesn't. The reason is that there is no scala-2.9.2 build for Play in maven (except for play 2.10 snapshots). Two options: compile play yourself or file a bug report so they provide such a build.

Comment: I just filed such a bug report -- let's see how it turns out: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/837

Answer (score 1):

you can change the scala version in sbt. Not sure whether there is play sbt plugin for 2.9.2 yet.

[How to change Scala version for sbt project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888031/changing-scala-version-in-existing-sbt-project)

Comment: I'm not using the light configuration.  Using `set build.scala.version 2.9.2` gives an error: `eof expected but double literal found.`

Comment: you need to separate settings with an empty line